# From a state transition table, how do I determine if I'm dealing with a Mealy or Moore machine?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

From the state transition table below, how do I know if I'm constructing circuits for a Mealy or a Moore machine? Could someone explain the difference and what I should be looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `Z` is determined solely by the state and not the inputs. Therefore the machine is a Moore machine.

From Wikipedia:

> ...a Mealy machine is a finite-state machine whose output values are determined both by its current state and the current inputs.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine))

> ..a Moore machine is a finite-state machine whose output values are determined only by its current state.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine))